# How to use functions in array value assignment in php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I assign a value to an associated array key which is the output of some function call? A code example might make it clear...

```
$myArray = ['k' => myFunction(arg1)];
```

Comment: Have you even just *tried* your code?

Comment: why wouldn't this work? it'd take you about 10 seconds to write this and execute it, which is way less time than it'd have taken to log in here and type it up and wait for an answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 too scared to do this.

Comment: @u_mulder The computer won't explode. Or at least most of the times not.

Comment: It was stupid on my part, the error was somewhere else. I guess the late working hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$myArray['k'] = myFunction(arg1);

Answer (score 0):

Define a function and then make a function call in the array as below.

```
function myFunction ($number)
{
    return $number;
}
$arr = array ( 4 => myFunction(5) );
echo '<pre>',print_r($arr),'</pre';
```

output

```
Array
(
    [4] => 5
)
1
```